# django : order queryset by model method without converting to list

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

i have a model `Complaint` with `get_latest_response` method

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
    message         = models.TextField(blank=True)
    email           = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_latest_response(self):
        return ResponseLetter.objects.filter(complaint=self)[:1][0]
```

method `get_latest_response` return the latest respone to this complaint

and `ResponseLetter` model

```
class ResponseLetter(models.Model): 
    date_response       = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    response_content    = models.TextField()
    response_from       = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    complaint           = models.ForeignKey(Complaint)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_response"]
```

then in `view` i get complaints (`queryset`)

```
complaints = Complaint.objects.all()
```

and i have to order these `complaints` by  `get_latest_response().date_response`

but! i cant convert this `queryset` to `list` like

```
complaints = list(complaints)
complaints.sort(key=lambda x: x.get_latest_response().date_response)
```

because after that i render this `queryset` in `object_list` :

```
return object_list(request, template_name = 'complaint/complaints.html',
        queryset = complaints, paginate_by = COMPLAINTS_PAGE_SIZE,
        extra_context=extra_context
    )
```

also method :

```
sorted(complaints, key=lambda a: a.get_latest_response().date_response)
```

doesnt work too

can you give me any advice please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to list Complaints ordered by ResponseLetter.date_response. But order_by and distinct don't [play well together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). Here's a workaround:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Complaint.objects.annotate(max=Max('responseletter__date_response')).order_by('-max')
```

[Tested/working](https://github.com/jpic/django_test/tree/so_13494681).

Comment: but with select_related i will get all responded letters, so there will be duplicates of complaint. so i have to group by complaint, but group doing after order

Comment: but ResponseLetter has ForeignKey to Complaint. should your method work ? so i have tried, it returns wrong data ( there are duplicates of complaints)